# How to add value to already existing state in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have a state property called `projectname`

```
this.state={
  projectname: ""
}
```

I need to change the state value  (for example from "Project" to "Project-01" ) when a button is clicked.

Here state `projectname` changes dynamically. I want to know to how to add -01 with project name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `this.setState()` to change your component's state.

The common way to do this by using the `onPress` handler of the `Button` component:

- create a class method that uses `this.setState`
- bind such method in the class constructor
- pass the method to the `onPress` prop of a `Button`

Here is an example

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Button } from "react-native";

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      projectname: "Project", // Inital value in your example
    };

    // Binding the method that will handle the click.
    this.onClickHandler = this.onClickHandler.bind(this); 
  }

  // The actual method that will alter the state.
  onClickHandler() {
    this.setState({
      projectname: "Project-01",
    });
  }

  render() {
    return() (
      <View>
        {/* A button with the method passed to onPress. */}
        <Button title="Click me" onPress={this.onClickHandler} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

---

Now, if you explicitly want to *add* "-01" to the `projectname` value, you need to reference the current value of `projectname` when altering the state:

```
  onClickHandler() {
    this.setState({
      projectname: this.state.projectname + "-01"
    });
  }
```

But you have to be careful because multiple clicks will add multiple times "-01" (for example, 4 clicks will result in "Project-01-01-01-01").

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I got your point correctly or not but I think you are looking for something like this

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      projectname:"projectname"
    };
     this.updateState= this.aba.bind(this)
  }

updateState () {
    this.setState({
      projectname : this.state.projectname.concat("-01")
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setState` method to change the state like this :

```
this.setState({
  projectname : "new Project name"
})
```